How to use/convert best.pt model of YOLOv8s to tensorflow.js
I trained a YOLOv8s model on custom dataset in google colab, I have the best.pt file and I want to make the model work on mobile app using react-native, I saw it can be done using TensorFlow.js but I havn't seen how to do it. Can someone please refrence me to a source that explain how can I convert it to something that can be run on the mobile using react-native. Thank you.
I don't know what to do, I just chatted with chat gpt

Try this tutorial from Ultralytics: https://docs.ultralytics.com/integrations/tfjs/
